# How to represent a "active group" relationship in a relational database?

Tags: sql, database, schema, one-to-many, database-normalization

I need to store maintain a table of "users" where one user can belong to many "groups". Within each group a user has a bunch of group-specific settings.

This is all very easy to achieve with a Group table, a User table and UserGroupSettings cross-reference[1] table. No problems here.

The issue I'm grappling though is how to represent an "active group" relationship between a user and the group in which they are currently "active". A user can either be inactive, or active in one group at a time. When they are inactive, their UserGroupSettings are maintained.

The obvious approach of having a nullable "active_group" column within the User table doesn't seem optimal, as the database schema wouldn't enforce the fact that a row must exist within the UserGroupSettings table for any given Group and User ID. Likewise, having a "settings_id" foreign key column in the User table wouldn't enforce that the settings row that it pointed to actually referred to the same user.

Is there an optimal solution?

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: I don't get the problem.  The user would be inactive in a group if there were a row in `UserGroupSettings`.  You can also have a foreign key reference from `UserGroupSettings` back to `User.ActiveGroup`.

Comment: The users settings in UserGroupSettings are there regardless of what User.ActiveGroup is set to. For example, you can be a member of 2 clubs but you can only at one at once, or none (NULL).

The problem is I don't want to write code to manually maintain the precondition that when User1.ActiveGroup is set to Group1 there always corresponding entry for (User1, Group1) in the UserGroupSettings table.

Comment: . . That is easily handled using a foreign key reference.

Comment: I don't see how? If the UserGroupSettings table contains SettingsID (primary key), GroupID (foreign key), UserID (foreign key), and a bunch of settings, how do I make User.ActiveGroup a foreign key to SettingsID and still guarantee that that UserGroupSettings.UserID = User.ID by construction?  It will still be possible to insert a user in to the database that references a settings entry for another user.

That is no better off than enforcing the original constraint.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a table of, say, user_active_group, with a foreign key that references the user's group settings.

Something along these lines . . .

```
-- Assumes {group_id, user_id) is unique. 
create table user_group_settings (
  settings_id integer primary key,
  user_id integer not null,
  group_id integer not null,
  bunch_of_settings char(1) not null default 'X',
  unique (user_id, group_id)
);

create table user_active_group (
  -- This primary key constraint means each user can have only one row.
  user_id integer not null primary key,
  group_id integer not null,
  -- This foreign key constraint means there must also be a row in user_group_settings.
  foreign key (user_id, group_id) references user_group_settings (user_id, group_id)
    on update cascade,
  active_group varchar(5) not null
);
```

Cascading updates seems sensible. Cascading deletes is a little more application-dependent.